Why can I not post a question if the bot thinks it's a duplicate but isn't?
I have asked this question: According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?
Now I am trying to ask this question: According to Roman Catholicism does God have a soul?
The system will not let me post the question and there is a red notification below the "post" button which reads:  This post appears to be a duplicate of According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?
I have edited the questions to include specific tags to no avail.
I was hoping to ask a series of identical question of various individual denominations so as to get multiple answers without a "survey type question" because the definitions of "soul" are expected to be quite varied.
However, I am unable to publish question 2 because of question 1 even though they are definitely not duplicates.  What can I do here?  Am I forced to do a denomination survey question instead of multiple specifics?

oh that stinks,  I'm gonna raise that as a bug fix. I'll bet you can work around it if you substantially change the name of the title.  But their checkers are working against us in this case

@PeterTurner. Thank you. I'm considering asking the exact same question of six or eight major denominations and it's going to be hard to come up with a unique title for each one without losing sight of the actual question.
